# Android EditText hint

Tags: android

hi am using EditText and it's hint is ' Password(at least 12 char) ' both the text are in different size ie 'Password' and '(at least 12 char)' how can i set this ?

Comment: you want set hint on edittext..?

Comment: yes, but the hint sentence contain word with different size

Comment: I m not sure but i think it is not possible. may be change color of hint..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have found a way to do this by setting

```
editTextPassword.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<font size=\"16\">" + "Password     " + "</font>" + "<small>" + "(at least 12 charcters)" + "</small>" ));
```

and it work for me.

Comment: Awesome answer...great

Answer (score 1):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {           

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (arg0.length() == 0) { 
            // No entered text so will show hint
            editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, mHintTextSize);
        } else {
            editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, mRealTextSize);
        }
    }
});
```

And in `onCreate` you also need to change text size according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, changing the size of the text will affect the size of the hint...

```
<EditText 
 ...
android:textSize="14dp"/>
```