# Android EditText setHint's font size dynamically

Tags: android, android-edittext, font-size, dynamically-generated

I've been struggling with setting size of hints in my `EditText`. The hint's font size becomes too large and the layout starts to look horrible!

```
EditText dummy = new EditText();
dummy.setHint("some hint");
```

How do I dynamically and programmatically change the hint's font size w.r.t my priorly set `MAX_HINT_SIZE` (in pixels)?

Comment: You can use dummy.setHint(Html.fromHtml( "<font size=\"5\">" + "some hint"+"</font>"));

Comment: This is indeed what I feared. Not too pretty but it works, I'll hide it away in a separate class only focused on font sizes =) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something for you

```
editTextPassword.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<font size=\"16\">" + "Password " + "</font>" + "<small>" + "(at least 12 charcters)" + "</small>" ));
```

See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203477/android-edittext-hint)

Comment: Tank you! Was not able to find it myself =)