# Adjust EditText size to Hint

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Is it possible to adjust the EditText size to match the hint size? If not, what is the best way to allow users to enter their date of birth? I have a signup form and I used an EditText for all fields and the UI would be nicer with three EditTexts for each field (DD - MM - YYYY)

**Edit**

In the screenshot, the last 3 fields should be for date of birth. DD - MM - YYYY
In the month and year fields there is a hint but it's not shown.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a `width` attribute solved it.

```
<EditText
   android:id="@+id/input_dob_year"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:width="100dp"
   android:hint="YYYY"
   android:inputType="number"
   android:paddingRight="50dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common and convenient way to do it is to use a date (time) picker.

[image]

Since it is a dialog box, you could call it from a button like this:

`<Button 
    android:layout_width="..." 
    android:layout_height="..."
    android:text="Select birthdate" 
    android:onClick="selectDate" />`

and have it appear nicely adjusted to the device screen from the selectDate() method. Here are some examples: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping to find a way only using EditText

Answer (score 0):

It has been asked already. Try this one [Android EditText hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203477/android-edittext-hint)

EDIT: If you are looking for something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/txyNd.jpg

Then this is the code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="DD"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="MM"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="-"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="YYYY"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Simple use the android:hint for mentioning the hint. Used TextView for adding the hyphen.And you can use "android:weight" to balance the distance between the text views if you want some presentable decoration in your UI.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @MotassemJa Can you provide some code and a screenshot that you are currently using? It might help us to understand the issue.

Comment: Here you go, I added a screenshot.

Comment: @MotassemJa try the code i have added in the answer.

Comment: @MotassemJa if you are using a specific dp in your android:width, make sure you check it different screen sizes, it might cause some issues on low res screens.