# android edit text hint text size for different resolution

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint, text-size

I am developing an android application for all types of resolution. My app has couple of edit text with hint on it. The problem is that the hint text looks small for high resolution. So I want to change hint size for different resolution in switch case programmatically. Please help me with this or you can give me some better idea to handle this problem.

Comment: [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139676/android-edittext-hint-size) may help

Comment: I believe this also could save your problem:
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android

Comment: I think you have define various size in dimens.xml in values,values-large,values-xlarge.

Comment: I have define those xmls but it doesn't work for nexus 10.1 and resolution like 1024X600,1080X1920 so I am using switch case