# set different fonts for hint and text in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

I am using **floatlabelededittext** in my application. My requirement is to set 2 different fonts for **hint** and **text**. Is it possible? Then how?

Answer (score 0):

To have 2 different fonts for text and hint you need to use custom TypefaceSpan.

- Set a font to a text by using usual `setTypeface` method
- Set a font to a hint by using `SpannableString`

I already answered to that question [Android EditText hint uses the same font that the EditText has](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45438690/1808829)

You can also keep the same font and change the hint's size and style independently. To know how, please, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45456823/1808829)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is possible right now. But if you look at the source code of floatlabeledittext here https://github.com/wrapp/floatlabelededittext/blob/master/library/src/com/wrapp/floatlabelededittext/FloatLabeledEditText.java you see that it will be easy to add such feature.

All you need to do is to use `setTypeface` on the hint label `mHintTextView`.

Comment: there is no way to set the typeface to this library and is misleading