# Android EditText hint uses the same font that the EditText has

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml

I have defined a font for a EditText and now the EditText hint also shows that font, but i need to use a different font for EditText hint, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can change the font of EditText but you cannot change the typeface of hint.

Comment: you can do one thing change textsize dynamically. on textchange listener

Comment: @playmaker420 didn't see that post before, anyway thanks

Comment: This is not duplicate question. voting for reopen it.

Comment: AFAIK typeface works for all the text, one cannot separate for hints

Comment: @MikeM. yes exactly that is what I am talking about, what is your solution?

Answer (score 1):

> Android EditText hint uses the same font that the EditText has

EditText uses `textview_hint` layout to show `ErrorPopup` popup message.so try as to set different typeface for Hint as:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(<Pass context here>);
 TextView hintTextView = (TextView) inflater.inflate(
                        com.android.internal.R.layout.textview_hint, null);
 hintTextView.setTypeface(< Typeface Object>);
```

**EDIT:**
Because `EdiText` internally show Hint popup using `ErrorPopup`.

See following link for more help:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/Editor.java#Editor.invalidateTextDisplayList%28%29

Comment: Um, where does the OP say anything about the error pop-up?

Comment: @MikeM.: EditText uses internally `ErrorPopup ` to show hint message.

Comment: @MikeM.: Anything missing in Answer?

Comment: Naw, I just thought the OP was talking about the faded background hint, not a pop-up; [like here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/baIMB.png).

Answer (score 0):

No need to use reflection. You can achieve it by creating your own `TypefaceSpan`.

```
public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan
{
    private final Typeface mNewType;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(Typeface type)
    {
        super("");
        mNewType = type;
    }

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type)
    {
        super(family);
        mNewType = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds)
    {
        applyCustomTypeFace(ds, mNewType);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint)
    {
        applyCustomTypeFace(paint, mNewType);
    }

    private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf)
    {
        int oldStyle;
        Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
        if (old == null)
        {
            oldStyle = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            oldStyle = old.getStyle();
        }

        int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
        if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0)
        {
            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
        }

        if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0)
        {
            paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
        }

        paint.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

Use it as:

```
// set font to EditText itself
Typeface editTextTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font1.ttf");
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.normalEditText);
editText.setTypeface(editTextTypeface);

// set font to Hint
Typeface hintTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font2.ttf");
TypefaceSpan typefaceSpan = new CustomTypefaceSpan(hintTypeface);
SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("some hint text");
spannableString.setSpan(typefaceSpan, 0, spannableString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
editText.setHint(spannableString);
```