# How to change hint text size in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

Suppose I want to change text size. I'm doing it in code and it looks like this:

```
_textInputLayout.EditText.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip, 40);
```

When I write text in the entry it looks like 40dip text. But when entry is empty hint text looks like 16-18dip.

Is there any way to change hint text size?

Comment: I didn't try this with a `TextInputLayout`, but just a normal `EditText` and the call to `SetTextSize` was adjusting both the `Hint` size text and also the actual text when entered into the control and kept them the same size.  If you can produce a small demo I will take a further look at what you have?  If so my details are on my profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the final hint size / floating label size is possible via a style and calling `SetHintTextAppearance` using something like the following:-

```
_nativeView.SetHintTextAppearance(App6.Droid.Resource.Style.MyTextInputLayout);
```

Where `MyTextInputLayout` is something along the lines of:-

```
<style name="MyTextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">44sp</item>
</style>
```

However the `textSize` from this style is only applied to the final destination, when you start to enter some text in.

From what I can see, and including the properties on the object, it doesn't appear to be possible to change the starting font size of the hint unfortunately at the moment?

Where as `EditText` is exposed, and you can alter things there.  The `Hint` portion is not handled at all by it, and instead by the `TextInputLayout`.  There appears no object exposed to get access to customize this specifically for the `Hint`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by setting a size in the string recource.

For example:

```
<string name="edittext_hint"><font size="15">Hint here!</font></string>
```

then in your XML just write

```
android:hint="@string/edittext_hint"
```

This will resault in a smaller text for the hint but the original size for the input text.

Or like this:

```
MYEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                    int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                if (arg0.length() == 0) { 
                    // No entered text so will show hint
                    editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, mHintTextSize);
                } else {
                    editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, mRealTextSize);
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: Nice, but does't work for xamarin. I saw this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139676/android-edittext-hint-size and I've already tried it.