# TextInputLayout's floating hint text size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

In my layout I am using `EditText` inside `TextInputLayout`so I can have floating hint. Right now I would like to create some `TextViews` which sizes are equal to that of floating hint. But how can I know the right size value? Is it somehow determinant of a `EditText`'s `android:textSize`attribute?

Comment: Probably you want this: TextView.getTextSize()

Comment: I think, this should help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139676/android-edittext-hint-size

Comment: You can get hint size of EditText and Set as well which is equivalent to hint text size.

Comment: Do you want to give size floating hint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this.

**change `EditText`'s text size**

```
android:textSize="12sp"
```

You can do this in the `.java`.

```
editText.setTextSize(12);
```

**change `TextInputLayout`'s `LEFT-TOP` text size**

```
app:hintTextAppearance="@style/text_in_layout_hint_Style"
```

style code

```
<style name="text_in_layout_hint_Style">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

You can do this in `.java`.

```
textInputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.text_in_layout_hint_Style);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set it via styles

create `HintTextAppearance` style with

`<item name="android:textSize">Your text size</item>`

and set `app:hintTextAppearance="@style/Your style"` to your `InputTextLayout`

Comment: That is the size of EditText text size. I want size of floating hint which is small text over EditText when you start to type something