# Android - How to get hint size of TextInputLayout programmatically when focused?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

How to get hint size of Enter Email Id(mentioned in this image) ?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android EditText Hint Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139676/android-edittext-hint-size)

Comment: @Thunder i am not asked about edit text hint size. i want text input layout edit text hint size when text input layout edit text onFocused.

Answer (score 2):

Text size of `hint` *is same as the text to be inputed* in `TextInputLayout`. To get `textSize` in Java do like below:

XML:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="157dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="158dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/TextInputEditText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="hint" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    final TextInputEditText textInputEditText = findViewById(R.id.TextInputEditText);


    textInputEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            float size = textInputEditText.getTextSize();
            Log.i("TEXT_SIZE", String.valueOf(size));
        }
    });
```

If you want to change textSize you can use `textInputEditText.setTextSize();`

Comment: i am not asked about edit text hint size. i want text input layout edit text hint size when text input layout edit text  onFocused- @VicJordan

Comment: @AjithRamsaran check my updated answer. You can get textSize on focus of `TextInputEditText`

Comment: @AjithRamsaran did you check my answer?

Comment: Yeah @VicJordan

Comment: @AjithRamsaran  is this what you wanted? Please accept my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

For example:
For **get hint size** you need to get a `edittext` text size like this:

```
    EditText mEmailId= findViewById(R.id.et_email);
    mEmailId.getTextSize();
```

**String.xml**

```
<string name="edittext_hint"><font size="15">Hint set here</font></string>
```

**then in your XML just write**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_msg"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="@string/edittext_hint" />
```

**OR**

Reduce the font size on the `EditText` - that will reduce the size of the hint as well. i.e. `android:textSize="15dp"`

Comment: This is **wrong answer**. OP didn't ask to reduce the size, he just want to get size. Check my answer

Comment: yes agree @vicjordan answer doesn't relate to question

Comment: @Thunder please check my answer. Thanks

Comment: @vicJordan nice way to get textsize , when focus changes it does the trick , upvote from me.